# Onclick change of the button image from inline css and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to make an inline css that will onclick change the color or the image of the input button?

```
<div><input type="button" id="btn" style="background-image:url('old.png');width:36px;height:36px;" onclick="change();"></div>

function change() { 
    document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundImage=url('new.png');
}
```

How to complete this with JavaScript? I missed something...

Or is there maybe a html or css solution that is much easier?

Comment: You need to add quotes in your function document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundImage="url('new.png')";

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" id="btn" style="background-color:green;width:36px;height:36px;" onclick="change();">
```

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I edited my question. Its not working although I have now onclick()

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap string appropriately.

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundImage=url('new.png');
```

Should be

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundImage="url('new.png')";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/Anee/cUTj8/1/

You have `type="button"`. If you make it button it should be `onclick` and not `onchange`

```
<input type="button" id="btn" style="background-color:green;width:36px;height:36px;" onclick="change(this);">


function change(myinput) { 
   myinput.style.backgroundImage= "url('new.png')";
}
```